# Android set Normal status bar programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-statusbar

I've been working with Material design and CollapsingToolbarLayout and want to use Translucent Status Bar in one of the fragments.
I have MainActivity with AppTheme (in style.xml translucent status bar and overlaying are false). I have Fragment1 and Fragment2
Fragment1 is not supposed to have Translucent Status Bar. Just normal with primaryDarkColor. However, in Fragment2 I need to turn on Translucent Status Bar progromatically. I've achieved it by this way:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Making status bar transparent
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window w = getActivity().getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

And when I go back to Fragment1 again, Status Bar is hidden. I guess I should disable Translucent Status Bar onPause() or in onStop(). But dont know how to do it progromatically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change status bar color use setStatusBarColor(int color).use below code

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color));
```

Comment: Thanks! THats works. However, my Fragment1 View is now still overlaying the StatusBar (part of the Toolbar are now under status bar). How can I set windowActionModeOverlay to false progromatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin, you can set the status bar to the normal state with this code:

```
fun Activity.setStatusBarNormal() {
    window.apply {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            statusBarColor = getColorCompat(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
    }
}

fun Context.getColorCompat(@ColorRes colorId: Int) = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorId)
```